# execvp find wildcard -name "*.c"

Tags: c, wildcard, execvp

How can you run execvp with a "*.c". I can get it to work with a full name but not a wildcard. Any help would be greatly appreciated. This is what I have so far.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("running\n");    
    char* args[] = { "find", "-name", "one.c",  NULL};
    char * envp[] ={NULL};

    int pid = fork();

    switch(pid){
        case -1:
            perror("fork() failed");
            exit(1); 
        case 0: // child
            execvp(args[0], args);
            printf("after the exec\n"); 
        default: // parent 
            //wait(NULL);
            if(wait(NULL) == -1){
                perror("wait() failed"); 
            }
    }

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "cannot get it to work"? Please post a [mcve].

Comment: have you tried with `"` around `*.c` ?

Comment: @Tyker That makes no sense.

Comment: @melpomene what i mean is `"\"*.c\""`

Comment: @Tyker Yes, that is what makes no sense. `"` are interpreted by the shell. There is no shell involved here.

Comment: @melpomene yes you are right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must do your own wildcard expansion.  When you use the `exec()` family of functions, you are passing arguments almost directly to the new program.

If you want the replacing program to replace wildcards for you, you may well want to use a shell to do that (as `system()` does), but be careful, as you'll need to correctly quote for the shell.

Example:

```
char shell[] = "/bin/sh\0-c\0ls *.c";
char *args[] = { shell, shell+8, shell + 11, 0 };

execv("ls", args);
```

Note also that string literals are `const char*`, so shouldn't be used to populate a `char*[]`.

---

However, in the case of `find`, you probably *don't* want to expand the wildcard.  Here, there's no need to do anything special - just pass `*.c` as one of the arguments.  The `find` command (specifically the `-name` argument) requires a *pattern*, not a list of filenames, so there's no expansion to do:

```
char shell[] = "/usr/bin/find\0.\0-name\0*.c";
char *args[] = { shell, shell+14, shell + 16, shell+22, 0 };

execv("find", args);
```

Comment: That doesn't make sense in the context of `find -name "*.c"`. `find` does its own wildcard processing. You can't pass it a list of names in the current directory; what would that mean?

Comment: That's why I showed `ls` instead.  I couldn't understand why anyone would want to expand a wildcard for `find -name` - the usual issue in a shell is forgetting to quote it to *prevent* expansion!  I've voted to close the question as unclear.

Answer (score 0):

This is *by design*. Wildcard processing can be expensive because it requires to browse a folder. It is normally active by default in the shell, but not in API functions. One notable exception is `system` because it actually pass a command to the shell:

> The system() function hands the argument string to the command inter-
>        preter sh(1)

The `exec...` family functions do not do that and assume that the path is a real path and do not special processing for wildcard characters. Simply, the `exec[lv]p` take all folder from the PATH environment variable and try to find a file *with the exact name* in one of them.

You must use the `glob` function for wildcard processing. BTW, the shell programs use it...

Comment: That doesn't make sense in the context of `find -name "*.c"`. `find` does its own wildcard processing. You can't pass it a list of names in the current directory; what would that mean?

Comment: @melpomene : The shell interprets wildcards, unless you explicitely ask it not to do by *quoting* them...

Comment: Yes, I know. Look at the command OP is trying to run. Wildcard expansion is exactly not what's needed here because we're trying to use `find`'s built in wildcard processing.